# Why does --where option in mysqldump not work sometimes?

Tags: backup, where-clause, mysql, restore

I was doing a through backup-and-restore procedure and it was needed that I use the --where option in mysqldump to fetch only the data before October 2015 since inception. This was the command that I executed.

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --skip-add-locks colossal_db users --where="creation_date <= '2015-09-31'" | gzip > users.sql.gz
```

When I restored the dump, I found out that the table consisting the restored data contained data for October 2015 also. Why does it happen when I have put a where clause?

Answer (score 1):

All options have to come before the database and table names. Try:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --skip-add-locks--where="creation_date <= '2015-09-31'" colossal_db users  | gzip > users.sql.gz
```

Comment: But, it did work! I had 30 million records. And only 1000 of them were in the dump file post the where clause date. How could that have happened?

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Were those extra rows for October 1? Sounds like a timezone issue.

Comment: Didn't check the date, I should have checked! I'll check the next time I do that and update here. I deleted all records where creation_date > '2015-09-31'.